# html5 video canplay event with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, events

I have a dynamically added video element where I previously had an inline `oncanplay` script.

```
<video id="videoCurrent" type="video/mp4" oncanplay="displayVideoChapters(this);" controls>
```

The video element is added to a static div

```
<div id="videoDisplay"> </div>
```

I am now trying to attach the `canplay` event to the video element with jQuery from a scripts file linked in `<head>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#videoDisplay").on('canplay', 'video#videoCurrent', function() {
    console.log(this);
  });
});
```

However, nothing happens. I've tried other events; `loadstart`, `pause`, `play` with the same result. `mouseover` is the only event I can get to trigger the console.log(this).
What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the canplay event to the callback function which gets the dynamic video player from thumbnail image links.

```
$('#staticVideoPlayerContainer').on('click', 'a.videoUrl', function() {
    $.get('url', function(data) { 
        $("#videoDisplay").html(data);                   //Dynamic video player is added
        $("#videoCurrent")[0].oncanplay = function() {   //Event listener attached
            console.log(this);                           //Logs video on canplay
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if jquery have a "canplay" event, as I saw in the W3C schools for this canplay event but in plain javascript:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("videoCurrent");
vid.oncanplaythrough = function() {
    console.log("Can play through video without stopping");
    vid.play()
};
```

You might first try with that first piece of code, see if it works, I also recall that .play() function is the one used for playing videos in JavaScript, hope this helps.

Comment: Ah yes you seem to be be right, https://api.jquery.com/category/events/ does not list any play() events.

Answer (score -1):

You could use it like this, works just fine for me:

```
$('video').each(function(index, video) {

   $(video).on('canplay', function() {
     console.log(video, 'this video can play');
   });
});
```