# currentTime and tracking in HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to track video play progress in an HTML video. I need tracking for 0,25,50,75 and 100 percent. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, cant get the console.logs working. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soen9pyx/)

I get error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null

any help / advice please

```
var myPlayer = document.querySelector('video');
var percentageCompleted = 0;
var totalLength = 0;
var videoStarted, videoTwentyFive, videoFifty, videoSeventyFive, videoComplete = false;

myPlayer.on('timeupdate', getPercentage);

function getPercentage() {

    percentageCompleted = (myPlayer.currentTime() / totalLength) * 100;
    //console.log('percentage', (percentageCompleted+'%'));

    // is 0
    if ((!videoStarted) && (percentageCompleted > 0)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_STARTED');
        videoStarted = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playStart'
        });
    }
    // is 25
    if ((!videoTwentyFive) && (percentageCompleted > 25)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_25');
        videoTwentyFive = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playTwentyFive'
        });
    }
    // is 50
    if ((!videoFifty) && (percentageCompleted > 50)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_50');
        videoFifty = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playFifty'
        });
    }
    // is 75
    if ((!videoSeventyFive) && (percentageCompleted > 75)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_75');
        videoSeventyFive = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playSeventyFive'
        });
    }
    // is 100
    if ((!videoComplete) && (percentageCompleted > 99)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_100');
        videoComplete = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playComplete'
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: make sure that you are using right selector while selecting video element.

Comment: I have updated by answer based on the provided jsfiddle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT**

Updated my answer now that we have a jsfiddle. Please try this code out. Your totalLength was 0, and not representing the actual video duration. Also user3767069 was correct regarding the ontimeupdate callback. Also, you call currenttime as a property, not as a method.

```
var myPlayer = document.querySelector('#video');
var percentageCompleted = 0;
var totalLength;
var videoStarted, videoTwentyFive, videoFifty, videoSeventyFive, videoComplete = false;

myPlayer.ontimeupdate = function() {
    getPercentage()
};

function getPercentage() {
    totalLength = myPlayer.duration % 60;   
    percentageCompleted = (myPlayer.currentTime / totalLength) * 100;
    console.log(totalLength);
    console.log('percentage', (percentageCompleted+'%'));

    // is 0
    if ((!videoStarted) && (percentageCompleted > 0)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_STARTED');
        videoStarted = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playStart'
        });
    }
    // is 25
    if ((!videoTwentyFive) && (percentageCompleted > 25)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_25');
        videoTwentyFive = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playTwentyFive'
        });
    }
    // is 50
    if ((!videoFifty) && (percentageCompleted > 50)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_50');
        videoFifty = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playFifty'
        });
    }
    // is 75
    if ((!videoSeventyFive) && (percentageCompleted > 75)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_75');
        videoSeventyFive = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playSeventyFive'
        });
    }
    // is 100
    if ((!videoComplete) && (percentageCompleted > 99)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_100');
        videoComplete = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playComplete'
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: thanks but i dont think thats the issue, cos when i console 
document.querySelector('video'); i can see my video 
here is the fiddle

Comment: i got rid of that error now i get an other one saying

 myPlayer.on is not a function

Comment: Check out the new code above. Change ```myPlayer.on('timeupdate', getPercentage);``` to  ```myPlayer.ontimeupdate = function() {
    getPercentage()
};```

Comment: thanks James Pooley , this works not but on my console i get percentage NaN% ,where i should get the 25% 50% etc

Comment: Did you update the totalLength at the top?
```var totalLength = myPlayer.duration % 60;```

It is working for me with the above code.

Comment: thats strange i did the the totalLength and still not doing it . i will double check again

Comment: It is working in Firefox but not in Chrome, taking a look

Comment: Figured it out. Move the totalLength assignment into the function. Now works in Chrome. Updated my code above.

Comment: Glad to hear. If it all works out don't forget to mark the answer as solved. Thanks!

Comment: one more question James , how do we also check if the video loaded correctly and fire up an event

Comment: There is a "canplay" and "canplaythrough" event that you can listen for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/canplay  there is a link to the canplaythrough link as well. You can see an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43599384/9436750

Answer (score 2):

If the 'video' is tag you are using then try the below code:

```
var myPlayer = document.querySelector('video');

// Assign an ontimeupdate event to the video element, and execute a function 
// if the current playback position has changed

myPlayer.ontimeupdate = function() {getPercentage()};
```

Comment: thanks mate - i did exucute function but now i get 
myPlayer.currentTime is not a function

Comment: Check out my updated answer. You call currentTime like this. Remove the parenthesis

```percentageCompleted = (myPlayer.currentTime / totalLength) * 100;```

Answer (score 1):

Both the Fiddle and the correct answer forget to get the reference to #video

```js
myPlayer = document.querySelector('#video');
```

AFTER the page is loaded.

Here was my quick fix (taking the code from the selected answer)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", init);

var percentageCompleted = 0;
var totalLength;
var videoStarted, videoTwentyFive, videoFifty, videoSeventyFive, videoComplete = false;
var myPlayer;

function init(){
    myPlayer = document.querySelector('#video');    

    myPlayer.ontimeupdate = function () {
        getPercentage()
    };
}

function getPercentage() {
    totalLength = myPlayer.duration % 60;
    percentageCompleted = (myPlayer.currentTime / totalLength) * 100;
    console.log(totalLength);
    console.log('percentage', (percentageCompleted + '%'));

    // is 0
    if ((!videoStarted) && (percentageCompleted > 0)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_STARTED');
        videoStarted = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playStart'
        });
    }
    // is 25
    if ((!videoTwentyFive) && (percentageCompleted > 25)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_25');
        videoTwentyFive = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playTwentyFive'
        });
    }
    // is 50
    if ((!videoFifty) && (percentageCompleted > 50)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_50');
        videoFifty = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playFifty'
        });
    }
    // is 75
    if ((!videoSeventyFive) && (percentageCompleted > 75)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_75');
        videoSeventyFive = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playSeventyFive'
        });
    }
    // is 100
    if ((!videoComplete) && (percentageCompleted > 99)) {
        console.log('VIDEO_100');
        videoComplete = true;

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'playComplete'
        });
    }


}
```